# What minimal files needed for Microblaze rebuild

Tags: git, fpga, xilinx, microblaze

I am working on a Xilinx project that contains a microblaze design.  I am curious the minimal file set needed to store the hardware portion of the project in Git (or some other CM tool) and still be able to rebuild it on a different machine.  I have so far been unable to narrow it down, but there is a LOT of files generated that I am sure I can get rid of.  Inside the top directory there are also directories for _xps, bootloops, data, etc, hdl, implementation, pcores, revup, SDK, and synthesis.  Which directories are totally unneeded, and which files are a must within the remaining folders?

So far I have been unable to find a good list anywhere (and my attempts to narrow it down myself have been fruitless).

Answer (score 1):

There is a target in the makefile to clean up. IIRC its called `hwclean` - there used to be `swclean` also.

If you run those, you are left with a much more limited file set.  I seem to recall it leaves __xps which I think is unnecessary.

Coming at it the other way, off the top of my head, you need:

- the XMP, MHS and MSS files
- the `data` directory
- any project-local `pcores` that you have created
- the `etc` directory

That should get you an "empty" bitstream with no code in the microblaze BRAM

The software will be in an SDK folder outside of the tree (otherwise it can get deleted by the tools!).  The Eclipse clean does a reasonable job.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed Microblaze designs in the past and still maintain them now and currently use Perforce for SCM.  I did not do an exhaustive analysis of what the absolute minimal fileset you need to completely recreate the project, but before I lay out what I've found, let me ask a question or two.

Is this an XPS-centered design or are you instantiating a Microblaze softcore processor within a larger FPGA design, using either ISE, Planahead or Vivado?

What version of Xilinx tools are you using?  Which tool specifically are you using to create and work on the Microblaze hardware design?

My last design containing a Microblaze core was done with ISE v10.1, so if you're using newer tools, my advice may not be applicable.